# How to display chinese character in XML

Tags: xml

```
<fieldlist>
    <description><![CDATA[Text - footnote]]></description>
    <type><![CDATA[Text]]></type>
    <abscissa><![CDATA[67]]></abscissa>
    <ordinate><![CDATA[292]]></ordinate>
    <text><![CDATA[退货商品仅在交付时接受]]></text>
</fieldlist>
```

I Have xml code that displaying question mark only not displaying the Chinese character
how to Solved it i already Include `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

Displaying Chinese character